# Limiting number of folders returned in a directory listing in php

Tags: php, list, directory

I'm trying to list a directory of files which are updated each week. Each update is in a new folder, so I've written the php so that it reads the updates directory and lists all the folders with an icon image that's in each folder.

Everything is working wonderfully, but my problem is, that there are 100s of old updates, but really the most recent ones are the only ones that need to be listed... the last 20 weeks maximum really.

So, my question is, how do I limit the number of folders returned from the directory? I've done a search and don't fully understand the explanations I've found, so I thought I'd ask here.

Many thanks in advance,

Kirsty

```
$cols   = 6; # Number of columns to display 

echo '<div id="updates">';  
echo '<table><tr>
      <th><img class="new" src="new.gif" alt="new" width="39" height="20"></td>
      <th>&nbsp;</td>
      <th>&nbsp;</td>
      <th>&nbsp;</td>
      <th>&nbsp;</td>
      <th>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>';


    $dirs = scandir("update");
    $dirs = glob("update/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            rsort($dirs);
        foreach($dirs as $update) {
            foreach($dirs as $dir) {

            if($colCtr == 0) echo '<tr>';

            echo '<td><img src="' . $dir . '/5.jpg" alt=""></a></td>';

  $colCtr++;
  if ($colCtr == $cols){
      echo '</tr>';
      $colCtr = 0;
 }
}
}

echo '</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a limit. This simplified example will show up to 10 update directories.

- For each iteration decrease it.
- When the limit is down to 0, break out of the loop.

```php
$dirs = glob("update/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
rsort($dirs);

$limit = 10;
foreach($dirs as $update) {
    foreach($dirs as $dir) {
        echo $dir, PHP_EOL;
    }
    if(!--$limit) break;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! It works without the 
        echo $dir, PHP_EOL;line.

Comment: That line was only for testing purpose and to simplify the concept.